# Find Data in DataGridView - C#

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to make a program that searches in a DataGridView a text introduced in a TextBox. Id works until a certain point.
I want to write in another TextBox the value that it have found, but all it does is to write in that TextBox "-1". Why? Am I missing something or I am doing something wrong?

Here is my code:

```
    private void PopulateDataViewAndFind()
    {
        DataSet set1 = new DataSet();

        string sourceXml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" +
        "<music>" +
        "<recording><artist>Coldplay</artist><cd>X&amp;Y</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Dave Matthews</artist><cd>Under the Table and Dreaming</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>Natalie Merchant</artist><cd>Tigerlily</cd></recording>" +
        "<recording><artist>U2</artist><cd>How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb</cd></recording>" +
        "</music>";

        StringReader reader = new StringReader(sourceXml);
        set1.ReadXml(reader);

        DataTableCollection tables = set1.Tables;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);

        BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
        source1.DataSource = view1;

        dataGridView1.DataSource = source1;

        int itemFound = source1.Find("artist", textBox1.Text);
        source1.Position = itemFound;

        string cdFound = source1.Find("cd", textBox1.Text).ToString();
        textBox2.Text = cdFound;
    }
```

Please help, thanks! :)

Comment: what do the objects in your DataGrid look like?

Comment: artist name | song name For example: U2 | How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb.

Comment: yes, but is it a `string` "U2 | How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb", or is it an `Recording`-object with a property `Artist` and a property `CD`?

Comment: It is a string, sorry, I got confused :)

Comment: Then that's where I'd start, change the string to an object. Especially if you're going to continue hanging more properties to the recording. I don't think it's very smart to have multiple property-names ánd -values in 1 string..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
string cdFound = source1.Find("cd", textBox1.Text).ToString();
```

to:

```
string cdFound = ((DataRowView)source1.Current).Row["cd"].ToString();
```